# while (using an array cursor) vs foreach

Tags: php, list, foreach, while-loop, iteration

I am viewing a block of code which implements both of the following iteration methods at the same time.
I'm wondering if there is a practical difference between the two methods of iteration?

```
while (list($module) = each($module_list)) {
...
}
```

and

```
foreach ($module_list as $module) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is much more readable. There may be reasons to use the functions that implicitly change array cursors, but a simple iteration over all values is not such an occasion.